# Comparing 3 raster maps of continuous surface data in R

Tags: spatial, agreement-statistics, heatmap

I have 3 maps representing spatial distribution in hunting pressure. These maps were derived using different methods and I am now interested in comparing them to assess how they might differ/agree with each other and whether there are some similar spatial patterns (i.e. areas with higher vs lower hunting pressure). I have converted all 3 maps to a common comparable index but am not sure what the best approach would be to compare them.

There seems to be a lot of different suggestions but none that quite fit what I'm trying to look at:

Initially I was thinking of computing a confusion matrix and looking at the kappa level of agreement but this only makes sense for categorical variables.

For continuous ones a lot of people suggest doing a correlation but I read that this would make sense for a time-series but not for comparing just 2-3 individual raster maps to each other.

Comment: Correlation and agreement is not the same thing! This [stored search](https://www.google.no/search?q=measuring+agreement+between+maps&oq=measuring+agreement+between+maps&aqs=chrome..69i57.8233j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has useful hits